Splitting a dataset into equal parts [All possible halves]
I have a dataset. I want to split it into two equal parts. For example, if there are 10 columns, I want to get two datasets of 5 columns. As you can see, this can be done in choose(10, 5) / 2 = 126 different ways. How can I make sure that each split is done differently?
I've come this far. But the sample() function won't give me what I want.
# the data
data <- structure(list(V1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), V2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), V3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), V4 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

n1 <- ncol(data)
n2 <- ncol(data)/2
x1 <- colnames(data)

# the dataset can have an odd number of columns.
ifelse(n1%%2 == 0, MM <- sample(x1, n2), MM <- sample(x1, n2+1))

s1 <- data[MM]
s1

s2 <- data[!colnames(data) %in% MM]
s2

# s1 and s2 are completely different from each other.

mylist <- list(s1, s2)
mylist

I want to combine all possible halves into one list.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40291009/1412059

There is a function in RcppAlgos (I am the author) specifically for this task. It’s called comboGroups.
library(RcppAlgos)

## n1, n2, and data are all from OP example
apply(
    comboGroups(n1, 2), 1, \(r) {
        list(
            data[r[1:n2]],
            data[r[(n2 + 1):n1]]
        )
    }
)


You can use gtools::combinations to get all combinations and use this to generate the splits:
library(gtools)
split_data <- function(dat) {
  nc <- ncol(dat)
  ## get all combinations (TODO: add some logic to deal with nc being odd)
  sel <- combinations(nc, nc / 2L)
  ## however we need only half of them as the selection of the first half
  ## determines the other half
  sel_final <- sel[1:(nrow(sel) / 2L), ]
  apply(sel_final, 1L, function(set1) {
    set1_idx <- 1:ncol(dat) %in% set1
    set2_idx <- !set1_idx
    list(grp1 = dat[, set1_idx],
         grp2 = dat[, set2_idx])
  })
}

str(split_data(data))
# List of 3
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ grp1:'data.frame':        20 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ V1: num [1:20] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
#   .. ..$ V2: num [1:20] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
#   ..$ grp2:'data.frame':        20 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ V3: num [1:20] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
#   .. ..$ V4: num [1:20] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ grp1:'data.frame':        20 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ V1: num [1:20] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
#   .. ..$ V3: num [1:20] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
#   ..$ grp2:'data.frame':        20 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ V2: num [1:20] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
#   .. ..$ V4: num [1:20] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ grp1:'data.frame':        20 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ V1: num [1:20] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
#   .. ..$ V4: num [1:20] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
#   ..$ grp2:'data.frame':        20 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ V2: num [1:20] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
#   .. ..$ V3: num [1:20] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...


Thanks. It helped. Now I need to find a solution to solve the odd number of columns problem.

Here is another method:
a <- combn(ncol(data), 2, \(x) list(list(data[x], data[-x])))

b <- head(a, length(a)/2)
str(b)# Just to display

List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ V1: num [1:20] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
  .. ..$ V2: num [1:20] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ V3: num [1:20] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
  .. ..$ V4: num [1:20] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ V1: num [1:20] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
  .. ..$ V3: num [1:20] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ V2: num [1:20] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ V4: num [1:20] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ V1: num [1:20] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
  .. ..$ V4: num [1:20] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ V2: num [1:20] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ V3: num [1:20] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...


Using RcppAlgos::comboGeneral. Here an example for choose(4, 2) for sake of conciseness.
> stopifnot(nrow(data1) %% 2 == 0)  ## make sure, nrow is even
> n <- nrow(data1)
> RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(n, n/2, FUN= \(x) {
+   split(data1, rownames(data1) %in% x) |> setNames(LETTERS[seq_len(n/2)])
+ })
[[1]]
[[1]]$A
  V1 V2 V3 V4
3  0  0  1  1
4  1  0  0  1

[[1]]$B
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  0


[[2]]
[[2]]$A
  V1 V2 V3 V4
2  1  1  0  0
4  1  0  0  1

[[2]]$B
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  1


[[3]]
[[3]]$A
  V1 V2 V3 V4
2  1  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  1

[[3]]$B
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  1


[[4]]
[[4]]$A
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  1

[[4]]$B
  V1 V2 V3 V4
2  1  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  1


[[5]]
[[5]]$A
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  1

[[5]]$B
  V1 V2 V3 V4
2  1  1  0  0
4  1  0  0  1


[[6]]
[[6]]$A
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  0

[[6]]$B
  V1 V2 V3 V4
3  0  0  1  1
4  1  0  0  1


Data:
> dput(data1)
structure(list(V1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1), V2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0), V3 = c(0, 
0, 1, 0), V4 = c(0, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

